# Select the users are not friend of anyone

Tags: mysql, sql

[image]

Hi, I have these two tables: users and friends (friend_status = 1 means the request is sent, friend_status = 2 means they are friends). Now I want to select all users are not friend of anyone. How to do?

Assuming the current user is 1. I tried this but it seems to be wrong. Because it just shows the users who sent request but not being confirmed yet.

```
SELECT user_id, name, email
                FROM
                (
                    SELECT user_id, name, email
                    FROM users u INNER JOIN friends f ON u.user_id = f.sender
                    WHERE f.receiver = 1 AND friend_status <> 2
                    UNION
                    SELECT user_id, name, email
                    FROM users u INNER JOIN friends f ON u.user_id = f.receiver
                    WHERE f.sender = 1 AND friend_status <> 2
                ) T
                LIMIT 0, 10
```

Comment: Not friends mean, there should not be entry in frinds table ?

Comment: OK. So basically a user Id 1 don't have any friends means in friends means in friends table receiver id should not be of user ID 1, if exists also status is 1. right?

Comment: if user1 doesn't have any friend, there is no any row in "friends" has ((sender OR receiver = 1) AND friend_status = 2). friend_status = 2 means friends. If sender = 1 and friend_status = 2, it means user1 just sends request, not friend yet.

Comment: friend_id colum existence is not the problem. I may remove it later.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT
    a.user_id,
    a.name,
    a.email
FROM
    users a
LEFT JOIN
    friends b ON 
        a.user_id IN (b.sender, b.receiver) AND
        b.friend_status = 2
WHERE
    b.friend_id IS NULL
```

Here, we want to `LEFT JOIN` the `users` and `friends` tables on the condition that the user has either sent or received a request and that the friendship was accepted. If the user didn't meet both critera, then values in the joined `friends` table will be `NULL`.

Now we want the users that ***didn't*** meet the join criteria, so we filter out the ones that met the criteria with `WHERE b.friend_id IS NULL`, which will select users who either don't have any corresponding entries in the friends table (in sender/receiver fields) ***OR*** have corresponding entries ***BUT*** none of them having a `friend_status` of `2`.

Comment: Wow, it works like charm! BTW do you have any advice for me about the table structure?

Comment: Great! Glad to hear you found a good solution. Your table structure looks good; the only thing I would recommend is taking out `friend_id` and simply leaving the unique combination of `sender` and `receiver` as the primary key that identifies each row. I also hope you're not storing passwords in plaintext like that, but are in fact storing it as a fixed-length hash (perferably a bcrypt hash). Having said that, I cannot formulate any additional critique without also seeing the data types of each of your fields.

Comment: But if you're also keeping track of multiple request attempts (e.g. friend request sent, then rejected by receiver... friend request sent again to the same receiver sometime later, and accepted by the receiver), then you ***will*** have duplicate combinations of `sender -> receiver`, and a third field will be required such as an auto-incrementing `friend_id`, otherwise it's just adding a little unnecessary overhead.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution. Note that this may not perform as well as Zane's solution, but it does have the advantage of being less arcane:

```
SELECT * FROM users AS u
  WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT * FROM friends
      WHERE friend_status = 2
      AND (sender = u.user_id OR receiver = u.user_id)
  );
```

Should be simple enough to read: It selects every user that doesn't have any inbound or outbound friend relationships.

Comment: Are there specific reasons why you think this might not be as fast?

Comment: My experience has been that MySQL tends to optimize `EXISTS(...)` (and `NOT EXISTS`) queries poorly. You might still get lucky, though!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT user_id,name,email
FROM users
WHERE user_id NOT IN (
    SELECT sender FROM friends WHERE friend_status<>2
    UNION
    SELECT receiever FROM friends WHERE friend_status<>2
)
```

If anyone can post a more optimized solution than this, I'd like to see it!

Answer (score 0):

All users without any friend?

```
SELECT * FROM users 
WHERE user_id NOT IN(SELECT sender FROM friends WHERE friend_status=2)
AND user_id NOT IN(SELECT receiver FROM friends WHERE friend_status=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
U.User_ID,u.Name
From Users AS U
Where User_ID NOT IN 
(Select Sender From Friends Where Status=2) AND User_ID NOT IN 
(Select Receiver From Friends Where Status=2)
```