# Select the users are not friend of a specific user

Tags: mysql, sql

[image]

Hi, I have these two tables: users and friends (friend_status = 1 means the request is sent, friend_status = 2 means they are friends). Now I want to select all users are not friend of a specific user. How to do?

Assuming the current user is 1. I tried this SQL. It works but it's too long and slow. The first selects all users sent request to user1 but not accepted. The second selects all users receive request from user1. The third and the fourth selects all users is not in "friends" table.

```
SELECT user_id, name, email
                FROM
                (
                    SELECT user_id, name, email
                    FROM users u INNER JOIN friends f ON u.user_id = f.sender
                    WHERE f.receiver = 1 AND friend_status <> 2
                    UNION
                    SELECT user_id, name, email
                    FROM users u INNER JOIN friends f ON u.user_id = f.receiver
                    WHERE f.sender = 1 AND friend_status <> 2
            UNION
            SELECT u.user_id, u.name, u.email
                    FROM users u LEFT JOIN friends f ON u.user_id = f.sender
                    WHERE f.receiver IS NULL
                    GROUP BY user_id
                UNION 
            SELECT u.user_id, u.name, u.email
                    FROM users u LEFT JOIN friends f ON u.user_id = f.receiver
                    WHERE f.sender IS NULL
                    GROUP BY user_id
                ) T
        GROUP BY user_id
```

**Update:** Add a pic.
[image]

Comment: kindly provide us some data on http://www.sqlfiddle.com/ so we can test and answer

Comment: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/49302/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
    a.user_id,
    a.name,
    a.email,
    b.status IS NOT NULL AS friend_status
FROM
    users a
LEFT JOIN
    friends b ON 
        a.user_id IN (b.sender, b.receiver) AND
        1 IN (b.sender, b.receiver)
WHERE
    (b.friend_id IS NULL OR b.status <> 2) AND
    a.user_id <> 1
```

You had asked a question previously [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11183428/select-the-users-are-not-friend-of-anyone) - "Select users who aren't friends with anyone", and I provided an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11183475/1446794) which utilized a `LEFT JOIN`.

Building off of that, to select users who aren't friends with a ***specific*** user, we just simply need to add that specific user's ID to the `LEFT JOIN` condition (`1 IN (b.sender, b.receiver`).

*Minor Edit:* Unless the user can friend him/herself, it wouldn't make sense to also select the user who we're selecting against!! So I added `WHERE a.user_id <> 1`.

Comment: You again, thank you. It's complex a bit for me, so I can't adjust it as my need. :( Yes, of course he can't be friend with himself.

Comment: Hi, one more question. Why do you put multiple conditions in JOIN clause. It's strange to me because I was taught that conditions should be in WHERE clause. Could you give me some reference website about it? So far I just use ON a.some_id = b.some_id, never use IN with JOIN.

Comment: It's actually quite flexible, what else would you like to query on? Want users who have never even sent/received a request to/from user_id `1`? Just delete `b.status = 2`.

Comment: @Emerald214, `LEFT JOIN` is quite special in that the values in the joined table will simply become `NULL` if it doesn't satisfy **all** *join conditions*. If we put the JOIN conditions in the `WHERE` clause, it would simply exclude the row, which is what we don't want. Instead, we still want the users returned where the join condition does not satisfy (values in joined table become `NULL`) and we want to select only the users where the conditions did not satisfy.

Comment: One more favor, also the above query, I want to get the "friend_status" of the users sent request to the user#1 or receive it from user#1. For the users not in "friends" table, I want the friend_status = 0. I mean SELECT
    a.user_id,
    a.name,
    a.email, friend_status ...

Comment: No problem! Glad to hear you found a working solution and are progressing. If you get stuck or have more questions, just remember we are always willing to help you out here on S.O. =)

Comment: One more, what if user1 rejects user2 (friend_status = 3), then he accepts user2's second request. It means there are two rows in "friends" table and your query still select user2 because there is a row with friend_status = 3 although they are friends! @_@
See the picture I've updated.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to simplify this by using something like this:

```
SELECT user_id, name, email
FROM
(
    SELECT u.user_id, u.name, u.email
    FROM users u LEFT JOIN friends f ON u.user_id = f.sender
    WHERE IFNULL(friend_status,0) <> 2
    GROUP BY user_id
    UNION
    SELECT u.user_id, u.name, u.email
    FROM users u LEFT JOIN friends f ON u.user_id = f.receiver
    WHERE IFNULL(friend_status,0) <> 2
    GROUP BY user_id
) T
GROUP BY user_id
```

The IFNULL function returns the value of the first parameter, replacing NULLs with the value of the value second parameter. In this case it means that friend_status will be treated as 0 if there is no matching friend in the friends table, which allows you to reduce the number of selects in the UNION by half.

Comment: #1582 - Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'ISNULL'

Comment: I've corrected the SQL now. The correct function in MySQL is IFNULL (I'm used to SQL Server which uses ISNULL for this).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to perform the query on `user_id` 1:

```
SELECT user_id, name, email
FROM users AS u
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM friends AS f
                  WHERE (f.sender = u.user_id AND f.receiver = 1 AND f.friend_status = 2)
                  OR (f.sender = 1 AND f.receiver = u.user_id AND f.friend_status = 2)
                 )
AND u.user_id <> 1
```

The subquery fetches all the established friendship relationship in which user 1 is either the sender or the receiver. The outer query selects all users for which no such relationship exists. The user with ID 1 is excluded from the query using the last line, as, even if he cannot be friend with himself, I suppose that he should not appear in the final query result.

Comment: It works but I want to get "friend_status" in this SELECT as well.

Comment: Which "friend_status" are you interested in? The status if the returned user is the sender, or the receiver? And, what if no such relationship exists at all in the friends table?

Answer (score 1):

Try this query

```
select
  u.user_id,
  u.name,
  u.email,
  ifnull(f.friend_status,0) as Relation
from users as u
  left join friends as f
    on f.sender = u.user_id
where u.user_id not in(select
             sender
               from friends
               where sender = 1)
```

Here sender = 1 means the user id = 1. You can pass user id to restrict this condition. Also status 0 means he is not friend. and 1 , 2 , 3 are according to your rules